# Laravel Relations One to One and One to Many

Tags: json, laravel, scope, relationship

I have three models Class, Students and Studentinfo. Class and students are in a One to Many relationship and Sudents and studentinfo are in a one to one relationship.

While getting students from certain Class I get a list of data in an array.

What is the best way to get data from studentinfo for each student in the array?

I am trying to get this data in json format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd set up relationships like the following on the models, the important one being the `hasManythrough` relation:

```
// Class.php
public function students() {
    return $this->hasMany(Student::class);
}

public function studentInfo()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(StudentInfo::class, Student::class);
}


// Student.php
public function studentInfo() {
    return $this->hasOne(StudentInfo::class);
}

public function classes() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Class::class);
}

// StudentInfo.php
public function student() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Student::class);
}
```

> ... you may cast a model or collection to a string, which
>   will automatically call the  toJson method on the model or collection:

```
$json = (string)$class->studentInfo;
```

[Laravel Docs: Serialization](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-serialization#serializing-to-json)